# Codename one network manager waiting forever

Tags: networking, codenameone

With the latest build of Codename One network code that used to work has suddenly broken.

This code, which uses NetworkManager's addToQueueAndWait() method is now blocking forever. Even if a timeout is set.

This was working before the last update to Codename One.
Here is a sample code snippit:

```
    final int[] returnValue = new int[1];
    ConnectionRequest r = new ConnectionRequest() {

        @Override
        protected void readResponse(InputStream input) throws IOException {
            returnValue[0] = 2;
        }

    };
    r.setUrl(NetworkManager.getAutoDetectURL());
    r.setPost(false);
    r.setFailSilently(true);
    r.setTimeout(10000);
    NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueueAndWait(r);
    return returnValue[0];
```

Comment: I'm not aware of any change that should affect this. When did it last work and when did it stop working? Does the issue apply to the simulator/device and if the latter which device type?

Comment: This seems to be the case in the simulator and on iOS. It isn't specific to the above code, it seems to be if I have several network requests the later ones are suddenly failing. I'm trying to build a 3.3 iOS version to see if that is working but my device is not letting me update the build, will see what I can find out.

Comment: Ok so I got an iOS build installed, but it still is having the same issue.
This was definitely working and I haven't changed anything on my side.

Comment: I doubt it relates to that test case, I'm assuming you have some other code which is failing inconsistently due to race conditions.